# How to build a standardized RESTful Java API

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

I already know how to build a RESTFul API - but being honest my last API was not standardized or anything.

So while I start a new project I really want to learn how to build a standardized Java RESTful API. (Java / MySQL / JAX-Rs / JSON/XML)

Not sure if I want to use Hibernate since the level of abstraction seems "big" for me.

I would like to know which Frameworks you use. Some good tutorials would be also good (most of the tutorials I found were very old)

Thanks :)

Comment: This is too broad of a question to be answered in a few paragraphs, and will likely be based on opinions.  A standardized RESTful API does not specify any language, and that's the beauty of it.  You can write an API in any language that turns a URL into a request and returns a response, and even rewrite it in another language.  Choice of frameworks is usually based on personal preference.

Comment: what do you mean with 'standardized'

Comment: I think Google will give you better answer and references to online tutorials.  If you have specific question, you ask here, this is very broad

Comment: Sure. Problem is, that this is a very broad topic and google is bad in finding things if you don't know what to search. This is the reason why i asked this question here. Its not like i don't know google^^

Well - what i mean with standardized is for example a Framework.

Comment: SO is the wrong place if you ask for frameworks, libraries and stuff like that. As you already mentioned Java in combination with JAX-RS, get yourself familiar with the core concept - the framework will be interchangable once you have your JAX-RS classes. Furthermore, MySQL has almost nothing to do with RESTful APIs - this is just some internal implementation detail you have to decide on, the end-user however does not care if you run a MySQL DB or a MongoDB in your backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these videos will be very helpful if you're using java : [REST services](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn)